# MSOutlook Plugin-Adding the BCC in email

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I'm customizing the send button functionality of my Outlook. I want an email to send to bcc id as well when user clicks on send button. I added the BCC id using below code

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Application.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_itemsend);
}

void Application_itemsend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
    //  MessageBox.Show("cghd");
    Outlook.Application app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
    Outlook.MailItem mi = (Outlook.MailItem)app.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem;
    mi.BCC = "rg8051@gmail.com";
    mi.Display(false);
}
```

I am not getting any exception while debugging however my mail is not getting send when I clicks on send button it says some error with Outlook sending functionality.

Comment: What version of Outlook is this for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the event is firing because you have message box code in there that appears to have been used for debugging.

You are taking a fairly long way to get to the mail item and since Outlook add-ins are based on Interop (I believe that is still true), you may be hitting a bug in the way you are accessing the mail item.  It is passed into your event handler (first param).  Use that mail item.  Also, you are adding onto the default send events.  Therefore, Outlook will do the Display(false) for you.  Your event handler should simply be one line of code.

```
Item.BCC = "rg8051@gmail.com";
```